# linux keeps disconnecting from wireless network

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking

I'm running Arch Linux on an Acer laptop and my wirless connection doesn't stay up. After a while it disconnects, and when I try to reconnect I get stuck with a "Waiting for authorization" message. I have to retry several times before getting the connection stay up for few minutes. This happens with both networkmanager and wicd. The strange thing is that the iMac that sits next to the laptop connects fine, and when I use my laptop within the university wireless network it works normally.

How can I solve this problem?

EDIT: I've tried to connect [manually](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wireless_Setup#Manual_setup) following the steps

```
iwlist wlan0 scan
wpa_supplicant -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
dhcpcd wlan0
```

and it works, I can ping google.
However, looking to wpa supplicant output I see that it keeps connecting and disconnecting.
I'm using WPA2, and this seems to be a problem in authentication.

EDIT 2: as pointed out in the answers I forgot to mention my hardware/software specifications:

kernel:

```
Linux 3.0-ARCH
```

wireless card:

```
# lspci | grep -i net
07:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100
```

module used

```
# lsmod | grep -i 80211
mac80211     216021  1  iwlagn
```

I use a Netgear DGN1000 modem/router

My dmseg output is shown here http://pastebin.com/8Tf7iage

Answer (score 1):

Use `iwconfig` from the wireless-tools package to set the rate of transfer like this
As root

```
iwconfig wlan0 rate 50M
```

The connection should now be continuous & will survive reboot.

Comment: Thank you, but I've updated NetworkManager and now my connection stays up. iwconfig tells me that I'm using a 60M bit rate.
I'll keep in mind your solution in case the problem shows up again :)